# Existence of derivative at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I'm supposed to find for which values of $p$ and $q$ the following function is differentiable at the origin:

$$   
f(x,y,z) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \dfrac{(x^2y^2)^p(1-\cos(z))^q}{x^2+y^2+z^2} & \text{if } (x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0) \\
        0 & \text{if } (x,y,z) = (0,0,0)\\
      \end{cases}
$$

I've made some progress using the Taylor expansion of the cosine about $0$, but couldn't get far even doing so. Could anyone share a solution?

Comment: Use $1-\cos(z) \approx z^2/2$ to get rid of the cos. Then the numerator is $x^{2p}y^{2p}z^{2q}$.

Comment: How about the slightly easier question.  For what value of $p,q$ is  $f(x,y,z)$ continous at the origin?  Converting to spherical coordinates will help to answer that.  Then when you differentiate what happens to the degree of the exponents?  And when will the derivatives be continuous at the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full solution as you asked, following previously given hints. Notice that using Taylor's expansion as you suggested gives us the numerator $(x^{2p}y^{2p}z^{2q})/2$, so that
the limit we want to be zero becomes
$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{f(x,y,z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}} = \lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x^{2p}y^{2p}z^{2q}}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}.$$

The trick lies in using the next three inequalities

$$ x^2 \leq x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$$
$$ y^2 \leq x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$$
$$ z^2 \leq x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$$

to write

$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x^{2p}y^{2p}z^{2q}}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \leq \lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{2p+q}}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

from where it follows the limit is zero whenever $2p +q$ is strictly greater than $3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can check that the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0,0)$ are all $0.$ Thus $Df(0,0,0)$ exists iff

$$f(x,y,z) = f(0,0,0) + 0 +o((x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2})= o((x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2})$$

as $(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0).$ In other words, $Df(0,0,0)$ exists iff

$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{f(x,y,z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}} = 0.$$